# PHP variables are shown in the console when returned to Javascript with Json Encode

Tags: javascript, php, json, validation

I am performing some validation with js and php  but i came randomly to firebug inspect console and all the variables come up in the console as shown in the screenshot. I thought if i return a variable from PHP with `Json Encode` that will be hidden but it is visible in the console.

Is there a way to hide those values from showing to the user in the console?
The main logic of the validation is in Javascript with conditions like so below then i compare the values in JS if they are equal to the string in PHP.

```
$row1 = "10010010";$row2 = "01001001";$row3 = "00100100";$row4 = "10010010";
$row5 = "01001001";$row6 = "00100100";$row7 = "10010010";$row8 = "01001001";
    
    
echo json_encode([
    'row1' => $row1, 
    'row2' => $row2,
    'row3' => $row3, 
    'row4' => $row4, 
    'row5' => $row5, 
    'row6' => $row6, 
    'row7' => $row7, 
    'row8' => $row8]
);
```

In JS:

```
//logic of validation in JS

   if ( jsVariable === data.row1) //...
else //...
   if (jsVariable2 === data.row2) //...
else //...
```

[image]

Comment: No - you cannot hide the response from the PHP file because doing so would also block JavaScript from being able to use the data.

Comment: okay i unserstand.. i have to delete all the javascript validation code and make it in PHP

Comment: If it's some real sensitive data you could just encrypt the values and decrypt them serverside.. Proper encryption methods are near impossible to decrypt by brute force. Just food for thought if a complete rewrite to PHP is out of the question.

Comment: Look into using $_SESSIONS tho that may help you.

Comment: So i have an array in JS that is converted into string using js `join` method. How can i pass that variable into php for server-side validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some *very important* things to learn here:

1. *Everything* sent to the browser is visible to the user. This was true even before every browser shipped with debug tools, because the browser runs on the user's computer, so if the browser can see it, the user can see it.
2. Anything *run* on the browser is *under the control* of the user. This means that client-side validation should only be used for user-friendliness, never for security. All validation *must* be re-run on the server, because the user can submit whatever data they want.

You can pass encrypted or hashed data to the browser in order for it to be passed back, or you can pass an opaque token that allows you to look up a particular piece of data on the server when it's passed back (this is generally referred to as a "session").

Note that if you decrypt the data in the browser, the user can intercept the decrypted copy. In short, *never trust the browser*.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you find this validation logic okay? https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/simple-php-ajax-form-validation-example-from-scratchexample.html

Comment: In my case, I am not interested about security all i want is to somehow hide those values shown in the console for example,  instead of showing the answer i could show `???`

Comment: But why do you want to hide them? Who are you hiding them from? As for that validation, that is still *applying* the validation client-side; the user can't see how the validation works, but they can still disable it. If you then pass the user's data back to the server, you need to validate it again, because the user can send your server whatever data they want.

Comment: `But why do you want to hide them?` - It is easier for me to use Javascript-Jquery `Who are you hiding them from?` A student who is trying to do a simple project. If i use for example in php the if statements and if the answer is true i can return a string `a = "??"` instead of the answer and then compare that `a` in JS (`if(data.a =="??" alert("Correct answer");`)is a bad idea for simple projects?

Comment: OK, I was wondering if it was something like that. In that case, the simplest solution is a good old-fashioned form: submit the form, the server checks your answers (in $_POST) and tells you if you got it right. But if you want to make the UI a bit fancy, then yes, an AJAX call like the one you linked to would work. Sorry if the answer came out critical, but the relationship between server and client is something people often misunderstand, and it can have grave consequences if you base your security on that misunderstanding.